# How to delete many documents in a partitioned collection in Azure CosmosDB using MongoDB API

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver

Consider the following document type

```
class Info
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }  // used as partition key
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a collection using this

```
var bson = new BsonDocument
{
    { "shardCollection", "mydb.userInfo" },
    { "key", new BsonDocument(shardKey, "hashed") }
};
database.RunCommand(new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(bson));
```

To delete all documents that are older than a certain date, I tried this

```
collection.DeleteManyAsync(t => t.CreatedAt >= date);
```

But this fails with `Command delete failed: query in command must target a single shard key.` My question is, how should I efficently delete these documents across multiple partitions? I'm not looking for answers how to choose the partition key in this case. I think that there will be always cases where I have to run modifiying queries across all partitions.

I could first query for documents with `collection.Find(t => t.CreatedAt >= date)` and then run a `DeleteManyAsync(t => idsInThatPartition.Contains(t.Id) && t.UserId == thatPartitionKey)` for each group of partition key, but I really hope that there is a better way. Example code:

```
var affectedPartitions = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(i => i.CreatedAt >= date)
    .Group(i => i.UserId, group => new { Key = group.Key })
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var partition in affectedPartitions)
{
    await collection.DeleteManyAsync(
        i => i.CreatedAt >= date && i.UserId == partition.Key);
}
```

Comment: This might be another "Cosmos DB" specific thing related to the implementation. MongoDB will not issue that complaint with the "many" or "multi" variants. The error only throws from MongoDB when you use an `updateOne()` or `deleteOne()` and do not include the shard key. The most reasonable response here is since this is not MongoDB, don't expect it to do everything the same way MongoDB does it.

Comment: Just for reference: [Single Document Modification Operations in Sharded Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-requirements/).  And of course, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12292 but since you already posted there you should know that. In short, MongoDB itself works as designed.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you for your comment. Of course, that's a cosmosdb issue. I was already aware of the "multi" thing in MongoDB, but couldn't find how to do it in cosmosdb. Maybe the MongoDB tag is misleading... This question is more about working around the missing support for cross partition queries.

Comment: I understood that and my comments are probably more for clarity to "other readers" than for yourself. I would not hold out much hope, and mostly because myself and others have "cleaned up" various CosmosDB questions which come down to unsupported things that MongoDB actually does. There basically is a template answer on here which essentially says, "CosmosDB is not MongoDB, so don't expect it to work the same". I'm not sure if there is a native API way to do your queries, but it's pretty clear the MongoDB API compatibility is not done correctly here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and finally found that this is not currently possible, and that the Azure CosmosDb team is working on a solution, with a tentative to release in the firsts month of 2019

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/34813063-cosmosdb-mongo-api-delete-many-with-partition-ke

Wait and see :(

Comment: The fact that it's not possible was part of the question. The question here is how to efficiently workaround this. I cannot imagine that any serious, real world project can work on single partitions always.

Comment: FYI, The link I posted now says :

"Fixed in Cosmos DB API for Mongo DB server version 3.6." 

;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about C# syntax specific but I managed to work around this issue with a MongoDB Bulk Operation.

this solution is far from perfect but is the only way I could think to solve this.

this is an example of how I implemented this on Nodejs:

```
//First find all your document you want to Update/Delete
const res = await model.find(query).lean().exec()

//Initialize bulk operation object
var bulk = model.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

//Iterate the results
res.forEach((item: any) => {

    //Find your document with your shared key ( my shared key is the document _id)
    bulk.find({ _id: item._id }).removeOne();
})

//Check if should excute the bulk operation
if (bulk.length > 0)
    //Execute all operations at once
    return await bulk.execute();
```

Reference to MongoDB bulk operation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/